# Cannot install selenium 4

Tags: python, selenium, pip

When I do

```
pip install -U selenium
```

in the cmd it tells me it is up to date but I think there is a selenium 4, I found that in the documentation.
[image]`

I would really like to be able to create a new window

Comment: Have you checked which version you currently have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium 4 is currently in [alpha stage](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/4.0.0a6.post2/) To install it:

```
pip install --pre selenium==4.0.0a6.post2
```

Comment: Accepted 3 years later? Selenium 4 became stable long ago. :-))) But tnx anyway!